# Is it possible to train a model using JSON in CoreML or in XCode?

Tags: swift, coreml, coremltools

I'm pretty new to CoreML and was wondering if CoreML lets you train a model using JSON. I noticed that it allows .csv files downloaded on my PC, but I was wondering if you can perform some kind of URLSession or other ways... Is there some kind of way to do this only using CoreML and Swift? If not, should I learn to use other tools?

btw, I'm only using CoreML and haven't been exposed to Keras, Tensorflow yet. I'm just trying to integrate a feature into my SwiftUI app.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to use JSON data as your training data to feed into CreateML, you can take a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/mldatatable/3022551-init  if not, you have to be a bit more clear in your question.

Comment: Oh, thank you! This was the documentation I was looking for!